# locale prefix in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rail 3.0.9 app I have routes.rb:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'index#index'
  match '/:locale' => 'index#index', :locale => /ru|en/
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /ru|en/ do
    resources :pages, :only => [:show]
...
```

When going to / path in browser, 404 error is shown and message in logs:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 06 12:45:18 +0400 2011
  Processing by IndexController#index as HTML
Creating scope :limit. Overwriting existing method NewsItem.limit.
  ESC[1mESC[35mNewsItem Load (0.2ms)ESC[0m  SELECT `news_items`.* FROM `news_items` WHERE (category = 'events') ORDER BY published_at DESC
Rendered layouts/_mini_calendar.erb (29.5ms)
  ESC[1mESC[36mSQL (0.2ms)ESC[0m  ESC[1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM `news_items` WHERE (category = 'events') AND (published_at BETWEEN '2010-12-31 21:00:00' AND '2011-01-01 20:59:59')ESC[0m
  ESC[1mESC[35mSQL (0.2ms)ESC[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `news_items` WHERE (category = 'events') AND (published_at BETWEEN '2010-12-31 21:00:00' AND '2011-01-31 20:59:59')
  ESC[1mESC[36mNewsItem Load (0.2ms)ESC[0m  ESC[1mSELECT `news_items`.* FROM `news_items` WHERE (category = 'events') ORDER BY published_at DESC LIMIT 3ESC[0m
Rendered index/index.html.erb within layouts/static (212.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 220ms
No route matches {:locale=>#<NewsItem id: 20, title_ru: "event 2", description_ru: "<p>event description</p>", published_at: "2011-08-31 07:55:00", category: "events", created_at: "2011-08-31 07:55:26", updated_at: "2011-08-31 07:55:26", short_description_ru: "<p>descr</p>", title_en: nil, description_en: nil, short_description_en: nil>, :action=>"show", :controller=>"news_items"}
Rendered layouts/_head_static.erb (2.3ms)
Rendered layouts/_ga.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered layouts/_logo.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_copiny_widget.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered errors/404.html.erb within layouts/error (10.6ms)
```

It tries to get make strange link

```
No route matches {:locale=>#<NewsItem id: 20, title_ru: "event 2", description_ru: "<p>event description</p>", published_at: "2011-08-31 07:55:00", category: "events", created_at: "2011-08-31 07:55:26", updated_at: "2011-08-31 07:55:26", short_description_ru: "<p>descr</p>", title_en: nil, description_en: nil, short_description_en: nil>, :action=>"show", :controller=>"news_items"}
```

Problem is in line

```
<%= link_to l(news_item.published_at, :format => "%d.%m.%Y"), news_item %>
```

When I change it to

```
<%= link_to l(news_item.published_at, :format => "%d.%m.%Y"), :url => news_item %>
```

problem is solved.

1) Why news_item in first line is interpreted as :locale, not :url?

2) Is this a bug or maybe I miss something?

Thanks to all!

Finally I found the best solution:

```
def set_locale
  ...
  self.default_url_options[:locale] = params[:locale]
end
```

Comment: Do you have a before filter to set the locale?

Comment: What does news_item do? Paste it's definition. Try rearranging routes in your routes.rb: first the scope, then root, then match.

Comment: apneadiving - yes I have before filter setting locale

Comment: Mirko - rearranging routes didn't help.

Comment: Your route helpers need to know the :locale parameter, so I suppose you cannot use the automatic path-from-model way. Use the `news_path(locale, news_item)` construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve that we could do so:

```
def set_locale
  ...
  self.default_url_options[:locale] = params[:locale]
end
```

Comment: WHERE does this go? The ApplicationController?